# How to handle multiple indexes in numerical order

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I am making a bot for instagram that will automatically send messages out to my followers. I want it to message everyone but, I am not sure on how to do that.

Here is my code

```
@Test
public void SimpleTest() throws InterruptedException { //

driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/log_in_button")).click();


By path = By.xpath("//*[@text='Phone number, email or username']");
driver.findElement(path).sendKeys("draco_boys");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");`
    `Thread.sleep(5000);`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/next_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

By path2 = By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.ImageView[@index='3']"); 
Thread.sleep(7000);
driver.findElement(path2).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);

By path3 = By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='1']"); //first person in my messages
driver.findElement(path3).click(); 

By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
driver.findElement(path4).sendKeys("Hello");
```

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_thread_composer_button_send")).click();`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back")).click();
}


}
```

After it has messaged the first person in my messages, I want it to go back and do the same for the second person, for the third person, and so on. Does anyone know what command I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use driver.findElements(By) to get a list of all elements and loop through them. You just need to adapt your xpath in that way that it selects all persons and not only one. In the loop you send the message and go back.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate all your followers in webElement list like this

`List list1=d.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index]"));` //this will give u list of your followers .

Now you can iterate over it  like this

```
List list1=d.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index]"));
    for(WebElment list1:ele){

    driver.findElement(ele).click(); 
    By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
    driver.findElement(path4).sendKeys("Hello");
    driver.navigate().back()

    }
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: List list1=d.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index]")); In this line **"d"** was underlined red. Also, in this line driver.findElement(ele).click(); **"ele"** was underlined red.

Comment: d will be your driver